# Numbers aren't displaying for my output

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, random

I am trying to get the numbers display as my output from the ArrayList I have created. I asked the user how many numbers do they want in the ArrayList, then used a for loop to generate random numbers between 1-100 and they would be thrown into the ArrayList however many times the user wants the to be. I just can't get the to be displayed, here's my code:

The KNW_MyList class:

```
   public class KNW_MyList<T extends Number>
{
  //Create the array list object of type T
  ArrayList<T> al = new ArrayList<T>();

  /**
   * The adds method, add a number of type T to 
   * array list.
   * @param number, the number to be added.
   * */
  public void add( T number)
  {
    al.add(number);
  }

  /**
   * The largest method, returns the largest value in the 
   * array list.
   * */
  public T largest()
  {
    T large = al.get(0);

    //For-loop to find the largest value
    for(int x = 0; x < al.size(); x++)
    {
      if(al.get(x).toString().compareTo(large.toString()) > 0)
      {
        large = al.get(0);
      }
    }
    return large;
  }

  /**
   * The smallest method, returns the smallest value in the 
   * array list.
   * */
  public T smallest()
  {
    T small = al.get(0);

    //For-loop to find the largest value
    for(int x = 0; x < al.size(); x++)
    {
      if(al.get(x).toString().compareTo(small.toString()) < 0)
      {
        small = al.get(0);
      }
    }
    return small;
  }

  /**
   * The show method, wil show the elements in the array 
   * list.
   * */
  public void show()
  {
    System.out.println(al);
  }
}
```

Demo:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class KNW_MyListDemo
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    //Create random class
    Random rand = new Random();

int numbers;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

//Create ArrayList object
KNW_MyList<Number> numList = new KNW_MyList<Number>();

//Ask the user how many numbers they want in the array
System.out.println("How many numbers do you want?: ");
numbers = scan.nextInt();

if(numbers <= 0)
{
  System.out.println("Not Valid!");
}
else
{
  for(int x = 1; x >= numbers; x++)
  {
    int num = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    numList.add(num);
    x++;
  }

//Call the show method
System.out.println("Numbers in the array: ");
numList.show();
}

  }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my ArrayList or my forloop? I am not quite sure, am kinda new to array list so maybe this might or might not have any effect? I just wanna get the random numbers to display 'x' amount of times, 'x' being the number of times the user wants.

Comment: You're not showing the code for class `KNW_MyList`. Please read up on [mcve]

Comment: What is `KNW_MyList` ?

Answer (score 1):

a few bugs in your loop. It should be

```
for(int x = 0; x < numbers; x++)
{
    int num = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    numList.add(num);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume problem is with saving your numbers to list. Your condition in:

```
for(int x = 1; x >= numbers; x++)
```

makes loop almost never running, because loop is only true if x is bigger than `numbers`. You are starting with `x = 1` so only if `numbers` are exactly 1 your loop is kinda working. Kinda, because it will be infinite loop. Change it to

```
for(int x = 1; x <= numbers; x++)
```

and it should be fine.

---

**Edit**
Ayo K mentioned my mistake, I forgot equals in condition.
Also, you are incrementing your list twice, once in loop declaration, and once in body.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb! Thank you very much, I realized my problem as soon as I read the first line!

Comment: This answer will give a wrong output and add only `numbers-1` Numbers to the list

Comment: Yes, I noticed also that you are incrementing `x` twice. Ayo K is also right I will edit this.